# Create MongoDb Database with Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I try to create database with simple Python code and It does not work.

When I try to create database, I cant see my database name in python and MongoDb.

Also, When I create database in MongoDb I can see my database name in Python.
My Python version is 3.6

Can you help me please ?

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

mydb = client["mydatabase"]

print(client.list_database_names())
```

Comment: What is the error that you get when running this code?

Comment: Actually, I did not get error, I can not see my database name  when I try to list database names

Comment: Do you see your other database names, just not "mydatabase"?

Answer (score 6):

The new database isn't created until you do your first insert.

Try adding an insert like below (also creating a collection) and you should see your new db.

```py
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

mydb = client["mydatabase"]  # you can also use dot notation client.mydatabase
mydb.mycoll.insert_one({"test": 'test'})
print(client.list_database_names())
```

The database `mydatabase` is output in the list of database names.